# API for Windows Mobile synchronization

Tags: windows-mobile

I"m wondering how it would be possible to synchronize desktop and mobile application.

For example a note taking application in desktop and mobile version on both of them command Sync - how this could be implemented any API reference or tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably after what's called an "[ActiveSync Service Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms834164.aspx)".  Microsoft ships a sample implementation with all of the PocketPC/WinMo SDKs called "StockPor".